# How to mount tags added dynamically

Tags: javascript, user-interface, riot.js

I have two files (dialog.tag) and (radio.tag) included in the page, compiled and mounted with command `riot.mount('*')`

I am trying to dynamically add DOM elements to the already mounted riot tag (dialog):

```
<dialog-tag id="dialog">
   <div ref="body"></div>
</dialog-tag>
```

in another script that runs after the previous tag is mounted:

```
let dialog = document.getElementById("dialog")._tag;
dialog.refs.body.innerHtml = "<div><radio label='some label'></radio></div>"
```

What I want to do is have the **radio** tags compiled after they are added to the **dialog** tag. Is there a way to so?

Comment: There's no such a thing as "mounting" a DOM element; if you add elements to the DOM, they are on the DOM. Perhaps you mean something else, and in that case i'd advise rephrasing the question.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

i think you are going at it in a wrong way. i'd suggest using the riot builtin tag *yield* for such things. 
It makes it simpler and cleaner.
the tag definition:

```
<dialog-tag>
    </yield>
</dialog-tag>
```

then the usage

```
<dialog-tag id="kuku">

    dialog content... may include anything you want, including other tags

</dialog-tag>
```